# DOMDocument parse and validateOnParse succeeds, parse and validate separately fails

Tags: php, html, validation, dom

Here is the html file I am trying to validate:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Valid HTML4</title>
</head>
<body>

    <p>Such tidy</p>
    <p>Amaze</p>
    <p>Much HTML4</p>
    <p>Wow</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I have manually checked its validity against the w3c validator (https://validator.w3.org/check).

this "method of validation" succeeds ($string holds the contents of the above file):

```
    $dom = new \DOMDocument();
    $dom->validateOnParse = true;
    // this succeeds
    $dom->loadHTML($string));
```

this "method of validation" fails:

```
   $dom = new \DOMDocument();
   $dom->loadHTML($string);
   // this fails
   $dom->validate();
```

further background: php 7.4, LibXML 2.9+.  Windows 10.  Because of the delays built into the W3 server(s), I have tried to validate the file two ways:  the first is by letting the request go out to the W3 server (takes about a minute).  LibXML error message reports "failed to load external entity http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd".  The second method is by setting up an xml catalog in order to cache a local copy of strict.dtd.  In this instance I get an odd parser error at line 81 of strict.dtd where it complains that the entity Content-Type is not properly terminated.

It is important to me to be able to validate separately from parsing. Any help would be great.

Comment: hi there good day Doug - , LibXML 2.9 is known to be a good and interesting approach to your problem! As you allready mentioned i also think that it is important  to be able to validate separately from parsing. Did you have found out more in the meanwhile!? - love to hear from you